# Override parent class instance variable in subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, overriding

In PHP it's trivial to override properties of a class in a subclass. For instance:

```
class Generic_Enemy {
   protected $hp = 100;
   protected $str = 5;

   //... 
}

class Boss_Enemy extends Generic Enemy {
    protected $hp = 1000;
    protected $str = 25;
}
```

Which is extremely convenient because at-a-glance you can see in what ways the subclass differs from the parent class.

In AS3 the only way I've found is through getters, which really isn't elegant at all:

```
public class GenericEnemy {
   private var _hp:uint = 100;
   private var _str:uint = 25;

   public function get hp():uint {
      return _hp;
   }

   public function get str():uint {
      return _str;
   }
}

public class BossEnemy extends GenericEnemy {
   override public function get hp():uint {
      return 1000;
   }

   override public function get str():uint {
      return 25;
   }
}
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this that aligns with the PHP approach?

Specifically: let's say I'm writing an API that will let a developer easily spin off his own Enemies. I would rather document that you just have to override hp and str properties rather than explain that they have to create a new getter for each property they wish to override. It's a matter of trying to create the cleanest API and the easiest to document and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes ya just have to write the SO question in order to see the (obvious) answer:

```
public class GenericEnemy {
   protected var _hp:uint = 100;
   protected var _str:uint = 25;

   public function GenericEnemy(){
     //...
   }
}

public class BossEnemy extends GenericEnemy {
   public function BossEnemy(){
      _hp = 1000;
      _str = 50;

      super();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, you got it. Although you probably want to call super before doing anything else. Otherwise if you set values in the superclass constructor they'd end up overwriting what you set in the subclass. In AS3 you can omit the call to super and it will automatically call it before running the subclass constructor.

Comment: @Cadin, I was explicitly calling super() at the end of the subclass method in case the parent class constructor did something with the vars, just to make the code more portable.